# What do I call this hat(?) with sun protection on the sides?

Tags: clothing, gear-identification

It looks like a typical hat but also has fabric hanging down around the sides/back of your head for sun protection.

I saw one on the trail that was labeled North Face but I can't find anything like it on their website.

Not knowing what to call it I'm having no luck finding what the choices are for buying one.

Comment: I'm not sure whether they have an "official" name, but an image search for "flap cap" brings up quite a variety of styles.

Comment: @GregHewgill Aha!  That looks right!

Comment: [Here's a North Face one](https://www.hatsandcaps.co.uk/the-north-face-hats-sun-shield-flap-cap-dark-grey-grey/), which is termed as a "Flap Cap".  Personally, I think this looks pretty menacing and probably better suited to Trick or Treating.

Comment: They also do a Camouflage one which looks less menacing.

Comment: @Snow In that color, yes, it looks menacing.  The lighter versions don't.

Comment: Shemaghs also work well tucked under a hat, or wrapped on the head

Answer (score 6):

One name for it is a [Legionnaires Cap](https://www.google.com/search?q=legionnaires+cap&source=lnms&tbm=isch) or hat.

[image]

Comment: Yes, or Desert Cap, or Sahara Cap...

Comment: Those don't provide good side coverage.  (And I tried "Sahara Hat", didn't think of "Sahara cap".)

Comment: Did you follow the link in my answer? Some of them do, such as [this one](https://cdn.australiangear.com/media/catalog/product/cache/5/image/450x450/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/k/a/kalahari.1551722427.jpg).

Comment: @LorenPechtel - they vary a lot in quality, design and price. If you want a really good technical hat, I can recommend this: https://www.sundayafternoons.com/p/ultra-adventure-hat/. Very good coverage, and has proved durable so far. But it's not cheap.

Comment: @Tullochgorum That offers good coverage on the back but doesn't appear to offer good coverage to the sides.  Ears can burn, also.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - not really the place to discuss individual products, but I can assure you it protects ears well. It's also the best buy on a well-regarded review site that does extensive testing with multiple users. It's a good hat for serious sun exposure.

Comment: @Tullochgorum I found another hat on there that I think would do better.  I've ordered one, I'll see if it works as well in practice as it looks like it will.